# Draw OverlayWays with Mapsforge

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to draw a simple way, a route, in my Android app with Mapsforge. I have followed an example and I created single points, OverlayItems. But when I try to draw a route I don't see anything in my map. Can anybody help me? Here is my simple code:

```
    Paint wayPaint = new Paint();
    wayPaint.setColor(color.Chocolate);
    ArrayWayOverlay wayOverlay = new ArrayWayOverlay(wayPaint,wayPaint);
    GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint(41.38, 2.15);
    GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint(41.39, 2.15);
    GeoPoint gp3 = new GeoPoint(41.40, 2.15);
    GeoPoint gp4 = new GeoPoint(41.41, 2.15);
    OverlayWay way = new OverlayWay(new GeoPoint[][] { { gp1, gp2, gp3, gp4 } });
    wayOverlay.addWay(way);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(wayOverlay);
```

I don't know if I have to put markers somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try set the wayPaint Style and the stroke width, like this:

```
Paint wayPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
wayPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
wayPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
wayPaint.setAlpha(192);
wayPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
wayDefaultPaintFill.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);

ArrayWayOverlay wayOverlay = new ArrayWayOverlay(wayPaint,wayPaint);
//your points
OverlayWay way = new OverlayWay(new GeoPoint[][] { {geoPoint1,geoPoint2,... } });
wayOverlay.addWay(way);
mapView.Overlays().add(wayOverlay);
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

The `OverlayWay` api has been deprecated as of `v-0.4.0`. Since I had a hard time finding new ways to draw overlays on the map I thought I post this here.`Mapsforge` now has added the following types of overlays:

```
 1. Circle
 2. FixedPixelCircle
 3. Marker
 4. Polygon
 5. Polyline
```

All of the new classes extends the `Layer` class, making it easy to implement. You instantiate the required object and add it to the `MapView` like this.

```
// instantiating the paint object 
Paint paint = AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE.createPaint();
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
paint.setStyle(style);

// instantiating the polyline object
Polyline polyline = new Polyline(paint, AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);

// set lat lng for the polyline
List<LatLong> coordinateList = polyline.getLatLongs();
coordinateList.add(latlng1);
coordinateList.add(latlng2);
coordinateList.add(latlng3);
coordinateList.add(latlng4);
coordinateList.add(latlng5);

// adding the layer to the mapview
mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(polyline);
```

There is also a mapsforge example [link](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-samples-android/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/samples/android/OverlayMapViewer.java) available.

Comment: Link seems to be dead