# Draw OverlayWays with Polyline?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, polyline, google-polyline, mapsforge

Could I draw a way in mapsforge the same way than google maps with *PolylineOptions*. It's much easier than this way. [Draw OverlayWays with Mapsforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708071/draw-overlayways-with-mapsforge)

This is in Google Maps. And I don't want to use Google Maps.

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new polylineOptions().addAll(PolyUtil.decode("ctlaGtkqU}@yIuAcMQ}@cEc^}@qHy@kJK_@sCg@aCsC{GuNwQma@}X}m@"))
                                        .color(Color.RED).width(3);
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your question exactly? Please try to provide a single sentence so everybody can see quickly whats the point :)

Comment: It's very easy. I want to draw a OverlayWays, but I wouldn't like to add all GeoPoints becuase I have a lot of GeoPoints

Comment: I guess MF has geospatial structures to make it indipendend on dataset extends and the dataamount. I guess otherwise you might need to add your own layer class that prefilters data during loading and skips adding to much :/